# How to properly load large number of items in dataview in Extjs?

Tags: extjs, store, dataview

I have a dataview ('Ext.view.View') that is bound to a store in viewModel, and dataview shows items correctly. But, the problem is that the whole store is loaded before the items are displayed, which might be slow when there is a large number of items. How can I load and show only one page of data and then when page is scrolled to the end to load another portion(s) of data? Instead of scrolling, button at the end of the page like 'Show more' is also acceptable.

I tried to add leadingBufferZone and pageSize in my store config, but nothing happens - the whole store is again loaded at the beggining except that this time network traffic shows limit:20 instead of limit:25.

How does this buffered store work?

```
  stores: {
      items: {
          model: 'Admin.model.Item',
          autoLoad: true,
          //leadingBufferZone: 60,
          //pageSize: 20,         
      }
  }
```

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('Image', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [{
                name: 'src',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'caption',
                type: 'string'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            id: 'imagesStore',
            model: 'Image',
            data: [{
                src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg',
                caption: 'Drawing & Charts'
            }, {
                src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/lights600x400.jpg',
                caption: 'Advanced Data'
            }, {
                src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg',
                caption: 'Overhauled Theme'
            }, {
                src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg',
                caption: 'Performance Tuned'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('imagesStore'),
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<div class="card" style="padding-left: 32px;">',
                '<div><button type="button" class="btn"><span class="btnSpan">Button</span></button></div>',
                '<div class="img"><img src="{src}" class="imgClass"></div>',
                '</div>',
            ),
            itemSelector: 'div.card',
            emptyText: 'No images available',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: AFAIK DataView does not support buffered store. You can implement some pagination or use Ext.grid.Panel instead..

Comment: Thanks. So what would be equivalent component for making cards like for example linkedin posts? I've thought that dataview is most suitable for something like that, although it is very troublesome to write templates.

Comment: Please provide some fiddle sample with the your dataview.

Comment: I added a sample, but this is exactly what I don't understand. If I would like to design a card (like linkedin post) what component is most suitable for that? Is it possible somehow to nest a container or panel as dataview item? Or it is done using dataview with complex itemTpl, or would it be Ext.grid.Panel (but then again styiling of rows remains as a problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can replace the DataView with Grid with templatecolumn. There you can use buffered store or pagination..

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('Image', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [{
                name: 'src',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'caption',
                type: 'string'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            id: 'imagesStore',
            model: 'Image',
            data: [{
                src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg',
                caption: 'Drawing & Charts'
            }, {
                src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/lights600x400.jpg',
                caption: 'Advanced Data'
            }, {
                src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg',
                caption: 'Overhauled Theme'
            }, {
                src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg',
                caption: 'Performance Tuned'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('imagesStore'),
            columns: [{
                text: 'Department (Yrs)',
                xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<div class="card" style="padding-left: 32px;">',
                    '<div><button type="button" class="btn"><span class="btnSpan">Button</span></button></div>',
                    '<div class="img"><img src="{src}" class="imgClass"></div>',
                    '</div>',
                ),
                flex: 1
            }],
            height: 600,
            hideHeaders: true,
            rowLines: true,
            trackMouseOver: false,
            viewConfig: {
                stripeRows: false
            },
            rowLines: false,
            disableSelection: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: One more question please. Is pagination applied automatically, or it has to be handled on server side? I mean, if I load the first 20 records, and then press 'show more' button, do I need to send extra parameters to server to fetch the next 20 records in another call?

Comment: On front end side it will automatically send appropriate "start" and "limit" params. On the back end side you will have to implement appropriate logic or use some ready plugins/libs for REST interface.. If you are using mysql/mariaDB you can use LIMIT __START__, __LIMIT__

Comment: Yes, I am using mysql, and I understand the 'limit start, limit' when I return the records from ordered table. But, what if I would like to return records that are shuffled (randomly ordered)?

Comment: Have a look at the 'sorters' and 'remoteSort' properties of the Ext.data.Store.